# Delphi XE2 - DFM stream is randomly empty or corrupted while read function callback is called

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, corruption, dfm

I'm creating a package in which a custom image list reads and writes its content inside a DFM file.

The code I wrote works globally well in all compilers between XE7 and 10.3 Rio. However I have a strange issue in XE2. With this particular compiler, I sometimes receives an empty stream content while the DFM is read, and sometimes a corrupted content.

My custom image list is built above a standard TImageList. I register my read callback this way:

```pascal
procedure TMyImageList.DefineProperties(pFiler: TFiler);
    function DoWritePictures: Boolean;
    begin
        if (Assigned(pFiler.Ancestor)) then
            Result := not (pFiler.Ancestor is TMyImageList)
        else
            Result := Count > 0;
    end;
begin
    inherited DefineProperties(pFiler);

    // register the properties that will load and save the pictures binary data in DFM files
    pFiler.DefineBinaryProperty('Pictures', ReadPictures, WritePictures, DoWritePictures);
end;
```

Here is the ReadPictures function:

```pascal
procedure TMyImageList.ReadPictures(pStream: TStream);
begin
    LoadPictureListFromStream(m_pPictures, pStream);
end;
```

Here is the LoadPictureListFromStream function:

```pascal
procedure TMyImageList.LoadPictureListFromStream(pList: IWPictureList; pStream: TStream);
var
    {$if CompilerVersion <= 23}
        pImgNameBytes: Pointer;
        pData:         Pointer;
    {$else}
        imgNameBytes:  TBytes;
    {$ifend}

    count, i:      Integer;
    color:         Cardinal;
    imgClassName:  string;
    pMemStr:       TMemoryStream;
    size:          Int64;
    pItem:         IWPictureItem;
    pGraphicClass: TGraphicClass;
    pGraphic:      TGraphic;
begin
    // read the list count
    pStream.ReadBuffer(count, SizeOf(count));

    // is list empty?
    if (count <= 0) then
        Exit;

    pMemStr := TMemoryStream.Create;

    // enable the code below to log the received stream content
    {$ifdef _DEBUG}
        size := pStream.Position;
        pStream.Position := 0;
        pMemStr.CopyFrom(pStream, pStream.Size);
        pMemStr.Position := 0;
        pMemStr.SaveToFile('__DfmStreamContent.bin');
        pMemStr.Clear;
        pStream.Position := size;
    {$endif}

    try
        for i := 0 to count - 1 do
        begin
            pItem := IWPictureItem.Create;

            try
                // read the next size
                pStream.ReadBuffer(size, SizeOf(size));

                // read the image type from stream
                if (size > 0) then
                begin
                    {$if CompilerVersion <= 23}
                        pImgNameBytes := nil;

                        try
                            GetMem(pImgNameBytes, size + 1);
                            pStream.ReadBuffer(pImgNameBytes^, size);
                            pData           := Pointer(NativeUInt(pImgNameBytes) + NativeUInt(size));
                            (PByte(pData))^ := 0;
                            imgClassName    := UTF8ToString(pImgNameBytes);
                        finally
                            if (Assigned(pImgNameBytes)) then
                                FreeMem(pImgNameBytes);
                        end;
                    {$else}
                        SetLength(imgNameBytes, size);
                        pStream.Read(imgNameBytes, size);
                        imgClassName := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(imgNameBytes);
                    {$ifend}
                end;

                // read the next size
                pStream.ReadBuffer(size, SizeOf(size));

                // read the image from stream
                if (size > 0) then
                begin
                    // read the image in a temporary memory stream
                    pMemStr.CopyFrom(pStream, size);
                    pMemStr.Position := 0;

                    // get the graphic class to create
                    if (imgClassName = 'TWSVGGraphic') then
                        pGraphicClass := TWSVGGraphic
                    else
                    begin
                        TWLogHelper.LogToCompiler('Internal error - unknown graphic class - '
                                + imgClassName + ' - name - ' + Name);
                        pGraphicClass := nil;
                    end;

                    // found it?
                    if (Assigned(pGraphicClass)) then
                    begin
                        pGraphic := nil;

                        try
                            // create a matching graphic to receive the image data
                            pGraphic := pGraphicClass.Create;
                            pGraphic.LoadFromStream(pMemStr);
                            pItem.m_pPicture.Assign(pGraphic);
                        finally
                            pGraphic.Free;
                        end;
                    end;

                    pMemStr.Clear;
                end;

                // read the next size
                pStream.ReadBuffer(size, SizeOf(size));

                // read the color key from stream
                if (size > 0) then
                begin
                    Assert(size = SizeOf(color));
                    pStream.ReadBuffer(color, size);

                    // get the color key
                    pItem.m_ColorKey := TWColor.Create((color shr 16) and $FF,
                                                       (color shr 8)  and $FF,
                                                        color         and $FF,
                                                       (color shr 24) and $FF);
                end;

                // add item to list
                pList.Add(pItem);
            except
                pItem.Free;
                raise;
            end;
        end;
    finally
        pMemStr.Free;
    end;
end;
```

Here is the WritePictures function:

```pascal
procedure TMyImageList.WritePictures(pStream: TStream);
begin
    SavePictureListToStream(m_pPictures, pStream);
end;
```

And finally, here is the SavePictureListToStream function:

```pascal
procedure TMyImageList.SavePictureListToStream(pList: IWPictureList; pStream: TStream);
var
    count, i:     Integer;
    color:        Cardinal;
    imgClassName: string;
    imgNameBytes: TBytes;
    pMemStr:      TMemoryStream;
    size:         Int64;
begin
    // write the list count
    count := pList.Count;
    pStream.WriteBuffer(count, SizeOf(count));

    if (count = 0) then
        Exit;

    pMemStr := TMemoryStream.Create;

    try
        for i := 0 to count - 1 do
        begin
            // a picture should always be assigned in the list so this should never happen
            if (not Assigned(pList[i].m_pPicture.Graphic)) then
            begin
                TWLogHelper.LogToCompiler('Internal error - picture list is corrupted - ' + Name);

                // write empty size to prevent to corrupt the stream
                size := 0;
                pStream.WriteBuffer(size, SizeOf(size));
                pStream.WriteBuffer(size, SizeOf(size));
            end
            else
            begin
                // save the image type in the stream
                imgClassName := pList[i].m_pPicture.Graphic.ClassName;
                imgNameBytes := TEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(imgClassName);
                size         := Length(imgNameBytes);
                pStream.WriteBuffer(size, SizeOf(size));
                pStream.Write(imgNameBytes, size);

                // save the image in the stream
                pList[i].m_pPicture.Graphic.SaveToStream(pMemStr);
                size := pMemStr.Size;
                pStream.WriteBuffer(size, SizeOf(size));
                pStream.CopyFrom(pMemStr, 0);
                pMemStr.Clear;
            end;

            // build the key color to save
            color := (pList[i].m_ColorKey.GetBlue          +
                     (pList[i].m_ColorKey.GetGreen shl 8)  +
                     (pList[i].m_ColorKey.GetRed   shl 16) +
                     (pList[i].m_ColorKey.GetAlpha shl 24));

            // save the key color in the stream
            size := SizeOf(color);
            pStream.WriteBuffer(size,  SizeOf(size));
            pStream.WriteBuffer(color, size);
        end;
    finally
        pMemStr.Free;
    end;
end;
```

When the issue occurs, the content get in imgClassName become incoherent, or sometimes the image count read on the LoadPictureListFromStream() function first line is equals to 0.

Writing the DFM stream content in a file, I also noticed that only the class name value is corrupted, other data seems OK.

This issue happens randomly, sometimes all works fine, especially if I start the app in runtime time without previously opening the form in design time, but it may also happen whereas I just open the form in design time, without changing nor saving nothing. On the other hand, this issue happen only with XE2. I never noticed it on any other compiler.

As I'm a c++ developer writing a Delphi code, and as I needed to adapt a part of the code to be able to compile it under XE2 (see the {$if CompilerVersion <= 23} statements), I probably doing something very bad with the memory, but I cannot figure out what exactly.

Can someone analyse this code and point me what is(are) my mistake(s)?

Comment: XE2 has TBytes and TEncoding, why do you have to fork?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your `SavePictureListToStream()` method, the statement

```pascal
pStream.Write(imgNameBytes, size);
```

does not work the way you expect in XE2 and earlier. `TStream` did not gain support for reading/writing `TBytes` arrays until XE3. As such, the above statement ends up writing to the memory address where the `imgNameBytes` variable itself is declared on the stack, not to the address where the variable is pointing to, where the array is allocated on the heap.

For XE2 and earlier, you need to use this statement instead:

```pascal
pStream.WriteBuffer(PByte(imgNameBytes)^, size);
```

What you have in your `LoadPictureListFromStream()` method is technically OK, but your UTF-8 handling is more complicated then it needs to be. `TEncoding` exists in XE2, as it was first introduced in D2009. But even in older versions, you can and should use a dynamic array instead of `GetMem()` to simplify your memory management and keep it consistent across multiple versions, eg:

```pascal
{$if CompilerVersion < 18.5}
type
  TBytes = array of byte;
{$ifend} 

var
  imgNameBytes: TBytes;
  ...
begin
  ... 
  // read the next size
  pStream.ReadBuffer(size, SizeOf(size));
  // read the image type from stream
  if (size > 0) then
  begin
    SetLength(imgNameBytes, size{$if CompilerVersion < 20}+1{$ifend});
    pStream.ReadBuffer(PByte(imgNameBytes)^, size);
    {$if CompilerVersion < 20}
    imgNameBytes[High(imgNameBytes)] := $0;
    imgClassName := UTF8ToString(PAnsiChar(pImgNameBytes));
    {$else}
    imgClassName := TEncoding.UTF8.GetString(imgNameBytes);
    {$ifend}
  end;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Thank you Remy for this detailed answer, I will apply it in my code as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you very much Remy, this worked perfectly and your explanations pointed me in clear words a mistake I was tracing since a long time. Your help was really precious for me.